# How to resolve import error scipy (rk45)?

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use RK45, but I get this import error.

```
   from scipy.integrate._ivp.rk import RK45
ImportError: No module named _ivp.rk
```

I have tried other suggestions online. Uninstalling scipy and reinstalling, etc. But no luck. I appreciate any help. I noticed when I run:

```
import scipy
print (scipy.__version__)
```

I get version 0.13.0b1. But terminal says its version 1.7

Comment: did you check in documentation? Maybe they removed this function. Or maybe it needs to install some extension. Or maybe it needs to install some C/C++ library.

Comment: your import works for `scipy 1.4.1`, `Python 3.8` on Linux Mint 20. It works also after updating to `1.7.0`. If you really have `0.13.0b1` then maybe you have too old version for this.